# The Key Pair was not found in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, anaconda, dask

I'm strict according to the anaconda introduction for setup my own cluster, seems have some issues, hope some one can help me.
https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-cluster/

1. I'm pretty sure my pem format keypair is correct.
2. Pretty sure the key id and key securet correct
3. The error below.

My provider configuration file

```
aws_east:
  cloud_provider: ec2
  keyname:  my-private-key
  location: us-east-1
  private_key: /home/master/Desktop/my-private-key.pem
  secret_id: A*********
  secret_key: AInbsUf*******





ERROR: The Key Pair 'my-private-key' was not found in AWS region us-east-1.  
master@ubuntu:~$ acluster create spark_cluster -p aws_profile_sample
Creating cluster
**********************************************************************
UserWarning:ssh private key /home/master/my-private-key.pem for provider aws_east does not exist
No license files found in: 
/home/master/.acluster
/home/master/.continuum
Using unlicensed limits.
Number of existing nodes: 0
Number of requested nodes: 4
Licensed nodes: 4
License is valid for the current number of nodes.
INFO: Creating new cluster "spark_cluster" with profile "aws_profile_sample"
INFO: Creating 4 instances
ERROR: The Key Pair 'my-private-key' was not found in AWS region us-east-1.  
Please create a new Key Pair on AWS or change the keyname configured in 

~/.acluster/providers.yaml
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the EC2 management console to view **Key Pairs**  in the US East (N.Virginia) region.

You should see a listing of keypairs and their names. Look for one called `my-private-key`.

If it's not there, then that's the reason it isn't connecting. You can create a new keypair from the console -- just use the new name and PEM file and it should work.

Comment: Hi, Johan. Thanks for the help, I re-create a new KeyPair it success now.

Comment: Hi @FLFLFLFL if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.